# backbone.js accessing model attributes within model - this.attribute VS this.get('attribute')?

Tags: backbone.js, model

From my understanding the attributes of a Backbone.js model are supposed to be declared as somewhat private member variables by saying

```
this.set({ attributeName: attributeValue })
// accessing the value
this.get('attributeName');
```

But when I am writing functions whitin the actual model it seems much simpler to say like this:

```
this.attributeName = attributeValue;
// accessing the value
this.attributeName;
```

Also I would assume that the latter version would be faster to process since it doesn't go through backbone.js's event management.

So I was wondering how you pros do with attributes that are primarily used internally in the model. These are the attributes that one would actually want to be a bit shielded from the outside so having them exposed like in the latter example maybe isn't right still. When I have been looking at examples for the backbone.js view which doesn't have get and set methods it seems fine to do like in the second example. So is there any nice rule of thumb when to use get/set(attribute) or this.attribute when coding within the model? Or maybe an example of a model that makes this clearer?

Comment: why would you want to avoid the backbone event management ? there could be views out there listening to certain attribute regardless if they are updated inside or outside the Backbone.Model ?

Comment: I just thought that when I for example in my application update some model attributes every 16th millisecond it wouldn't be a good idea to fire all those events each time? Most examples that I have come across are about Todo-lists and other things that doesn't update themselves that frequently.

Comment: For private model data I just do `this._propName`, rather than putting it in the managed area of a Backbone `Model` object.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**When to use `model.get(property)` and `model.set(...)`**

You should use `get` and `set` to access the model's *data*. This means any attributes that are part of the model's serialized representation that is retrieved using `fetch` and persisted using `save`.

**When to use `model.attributes.property`**

Never.

You should always use `get`, and especially `set`, instead of accessing the `model.attributes` object directly, although I've seen conflicting opinions about this. I believe there is a contract between a `model` and it's consumers, which guarantees that the consumer can be notified of any changes to the model's data using the `change` event. If you modify the internal attributes object directly, events are not sent and this contract is broken. Backbone events are *very* fast, especially if you don't have any listeners attached to them, and it's not a point that benefits from over-optimization on your part.

Although accessing the attributes directly instead of `get` is quite harmless on it's own, it should be avoided so the `attributes` object can be considered totally, completely private.

If you absolutely need to prevent some change triggering events, you can use the `silent:true` option: `model.set({key:val}, {silent:true})`. This does break the aforementioned contract, and even Backbone's own documentation gives the following caveat:

> Note that this is rarely, perhaps even never, a good idea. Passing through a specific flag in the options for your event callback to look at, and choose to ignore, will usually work out better.

**When to use `model.property`**

Any properties which are *not data*, i.e. temporary state variables, calculated properties etc. can be attached directly to the model entity. These properties should be considered temporary and transitive: they can be recreated upon model initialization or during its lifetime, but they should not be persisted, whether public or private. A typical naming convention is to prefix private properties with the `_` character as follows:

```
this._privateProperty = 'foo';
this.publicProperty = 'bar';
```

Comment: The answer Never may be suggested to a beginner. But if you ever work on a more complex project that works with larger data sets, you absolutely MUST work with model.attributes, because it is so much faster than using set/get methods with their overhead.

Comment: @jiri can you substantiate that with some perf tests?

Comment: If anyone wants to enforce this rule, you can use eslint backbone plugin https://github.com/ilyavolodin/eslint-plugin-backbone/blob/master/docs/rules/no-model-attributes.md

Answer (score 2):

Never is an incomplete answer.

Sometimes you want access to the collection of model attributes - whatever those attributes might be. Consider a utility method to perform calcs on attributes, format them for output, etc.

A convenient way to do this is to access model.attributes

Consider one alternative, below:

```
var attributesNames = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var attributes = _(attributesNames ).map(function(attr) { return model.get(attr); });

callSomeUtilityMethod(attributes);
```

Two problems:

- We've introduced coupling in the "attributeNames" collection. What if that list changes?
- We've lost the association of name/value. We could rewrite the map above, but it becomes more work.

In this scenario, it's much more convenient to do something like this:

```
callSomeUtilityMethod(model.attributes);
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing this. Not only are you exposing the internal attributes, but you're exposing it to another method that may not be aware that it represents the internal state of a model. If `callSomeUtilityMethod` method modifies the object it receives it as an argument, it (accidentally) also modifies the state of the model. 
 
In this case I would use `callSomeUtilityMethod(model.toJSON());`, which effectively clones the model's attributes and avoids any difficult to debug issues.

Comment: @jevakallio fine when your model only contains primitives. Not so fine when your model contains objects that you may want to be mutable in whatever function you're using.

Comment: BTW: I consider this a feature not a bug. Caveat emptor (hence the "Never is incomplete"). A potentially more serious issue is when you've overridden your model get() to do some clever "magic" which I do all the time.

Comment: not fine even when your model contains primitives. Consider `function callSomeUtilityMethod(options) { options.foo='bar'; }`, which still changes model's state.

Comment: Please see my comment: I consider this a feature not a bug. You can easily imagine broad categories of problems which require this paradigm.