# Directly access a Parse.Object's properties using dot notation

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, parse-platform

In Parse, to get to a property of an object, I need to use:

```
myObject.get("propertyName");
```

How to I make it so I can use

```
myObject.propertyName
```

Comment: JS object getters and setters.

Comment: what? Can you elaborate (or write an answer)?

Comment: [Some info here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/). There's also information on MDN.

Comment: MDN link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes property is the internal hash containing the model's state — usually (but not necessarily) a form of the JSON object representing the model data.

In Backbone model object has property attribute to which your data is attached.

when you say
 `model.set({'property':'value'});`

it will be like `model.attributes.property`

when you say `model.get('property')` what happens in model is

```
get: function(attr) {
      return this.attributes[attr];
    },
```

check documentation [here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-48)

Answer (score 0):

So the question is how can you circumvent the normal behaviour of accessing model properties through getters and setters?

Ignoring the obvious reasons why you shouldn't do this everything is available on the 'attributes' property.

```
myModel.attributes.propertyName
```

Or if you just need an plain object you could just JSONify your model.

Comment: I would love to hear the obvious reasons why I should not.

Comment: Also, can you give more information about "JSONify" the model? Because yes all I need here is a simple read-only object to pass to the view.

Comment: This has already been answered in another question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545697/backbone-js-accessing-model-attributes-within-model-this-attribute-vs-this-get 

I am of the view that if you have an interface for managing state, you should use it or you're going to hit unexpected behavior. My only disclaimer is that I don't fully understand your situation.

Comment: model.toJSON() - That's actually what a lot of frameworks do as a pre-cursor when passing models to templates. See: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/item-view.js#L22

Answer (score -1):

Little late to the game but this is what you're talking about.

https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-subclasses

Subclassing is completely optional, but can transform this code:

```
ParseObject shield = new ParseObject("Armor");
shield.put("displayName", "Wooden Shield");
shield.put("fireproof", false);
shield.put("rupees", 50);
```

Into this:

```
Armor shield = new Armor();
shield.setDisplayName("Wooden Shield");
shield.setFireproof(false);
shield.setRupees(50);
```